# How to send a message from a socket.io.client to symfony2 application with rachet

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Heey all,

I have a symfony2 application with Rachet which works pretty well. I can see logging when I access it with my browser so that part seemed to work.

I also have a nodejs application and now I want to send a message from that application to symfony. So what did I do:

My thought was to use the socket.io-client and do something like this:

```
var client = require("socket.io-client");
socket = client("tcp://domainname.dev:3344");
socket.emit('hello world');
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Already thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I've been through a lot of trial and error sessions but I've got it working.
Before I tell the answer I'll tell you what NOT to do.

### **Socket.io-client**

I started with the socket.io-client. Thanks to someone on Twitter I found out that the socketio client never couldn't work because the client has a specific handshake for making connections. (I couldn't find my source for that)

### **AutobahnJS**

So next option: AutobahnJS, I read on the website of Ratchet that it passed the Autobahn test suite http://socketo.me/docs/wamp. Peanuts I thought but I didn't got it working because the current version of AutobahnJS doesn't support the "old" version of WAMP (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ratchet-php/Szd2VV4EtXs) but AutobahnJS 0.8.* should. Unfortunately you can't install that version with NPM.

```
vagrant@dev:/var/www/quadstation.dev/quadstation-frontend$ sudo npm install autobahn@0.8.*
npm WARN package.json groundstation-quadcopter@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "autobahn@0.8.*"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: autobahn@'>=0.8.0 <0.9.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.0.0","0.9.0","0.9.0-2","0.9.0-3","0.9.0-4","0.9.0-5","0.9.1","0.9.1-3","0.9.1-4","0.9.2","0.9.3","0.9.4","0.9.4-2","0.9.5","0.9.6"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/quadstation.dev/quadstation-frontend/npm-debug.log

vagrant@dev:/var/www/quadstation.dev/quadstation-frontend$ npm install https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/archive/v0.8.2.tar.gz
npm WARN package.json groundstation-quadcopter@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/archive/v0.8.2.tar.gz"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-30480-482d323b/unpack-e44042007b9f/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/tmp/npm-30480-482d323b/unpack-e44042007b9f/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/quadstation.dev/quadstation-frontend/npm-debug.log
```

### **Websocket-Node**

After that one I became desperate and tried [Websockets-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node) but I didn't came further then connection refused but I didn't get any clear reason about why or how to solve it.

### **So whats the right solution then?  WS and a lot of reading**

I tried ws before but after some additional reading I gave it a second chance and I didn't got it working until I change a few things. My initial code looked like:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3344/', {
    protocolVersion: 8,
    origin: 'http://localhost'
});
```

After some reading about protocols I found out that protocolVersion 13 is related to [rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) + [What are the protocol differences between WebSockets versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239466/what-are-the-protocol-differences-between-websockets-versions)

I also found out (thanks to this thread: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36652) that using localhost caused me headaches as well. I changed it to 127.0.0.1 and finally I got a working situation.

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3344/', {
    protocolVersion: 13,
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1'
});
```

If someone has additional questions about this then let me know.